# Add a drop-box html tag in enyo

Tags: html, tags, enyo

I added a drop-down-list tag to my enyo code, but I'm not getting how to set the values inside it:

```
{tag:"select", classes:"myClass", components:[tag:"option"]}
```

How do I add options?

Comment: People can find problems with code that you share with them much more easier than with code you don't.

Comment: You haven't given us any code.

Comment: Ok.. here is just the line that i added.  {tag:"select", classes:"myClass", components:[tag:"option"]}....             And it's that. The problem is to know what code to add, for operating.

Answer (score 3):

If that is a direct c&p, then the problem is your components array declaration.  It needs to be an array of objects, so something like:

```
...components: [
    {tag: "option"}
]
...
```